# sum up some rows and some columns with Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've got a large dataset that simplified looks like this:

```
  Name  c1  c2  c3  c4
0   a1   1   2   2   3
1   a2   2   1   1   2
2   a3   3   1   2   1
3   a4   2   3   3   4
4   b1   1   2   2   3
5   b2   3   1   2   1
6   b3   2   1   2   1
7   b4   1   3   4   1
```

I want to sum up some of the columns and some of the rows to create an aggregated data frame that would look like this:

```
    Name  c1+c2  c3+c4
0  a1+a2      6      8
1  a3+a4      9     10
2  b1+b2      7      8
3  b3+b4      7      8
```

I've been trying to figure out how to do it with groupby and sum but I am pretty new to this and can't get my head around it. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: The fact that you groupby on non-unique groups is kind of counter intuitive. Does your data not have an unique identifier for each group? For example `a,b,c,d` in this case, since there are 4 groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to have unique identifier for the rows you need to combine i.e

```
uq_grp Name  c1  c2  c3  c4
grp1   a1   1   2   2   3
grp1   a2   2   1   1   2
grp2   a3   3   1   2   1
grp2   a4   2   3   3   4
grp3   b1   1   2   2   3
grp3   b2   3   1   2   1
```

**uq_grp** basically defines which rows need to be combine 
now do following:

```
df['c1+c2'] = df['c1']+df['c2']
df['c3+c4'] = df['c3']+df['c4']

uq_grp Name  c1  c2  c3  c4 c1+c2  c3+c4
grp1   a1    1   2   2   3    3     5
grp1   a2    2   1   1   2    3     3
grp2   a3    3   1   2   1    4     3
grp2   a4    2   3   3   4    5     7 
grp3   b1    1   2   2   3    3     5 
grp3   b2    3   1   2   1    4     3
```

Now combine rows on basis of uq_grp

```
df.groupby(['uq_grp'],as_index=False)[['c1+c2','c3+c4']].sum()
```

**result**

```
     Name  c1+c2  c3+c4
0  grp1      6      8
1  grp2      9     10
2  grp3      7      8
....
```

Comment: @double_h approve the post so that more people can benefit from it